# Razor Pages usable for creating interactive web apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Maybe my question is a little strange, but i need to create a diagram editor of a DRAKON visual algorithmic language (u can google it, it just represents normal code as a diagram).

At first i wanted to create it in Qt, where i have an experience. But my teacher asked me to create a web app, and now i'm stuck at choosing instruments. He advised me to try Razor Pages, but i'm not sure if it's usable for it, cause i'm not sure that its effective to render graphic in Razor Pages.

Basic functionality is:  create schemes, links and make an implementation of dragging them + editor window with block-scheme prefabs and solution explorer (explained just to let u know what type of app its gonna be)

Comment: Yes you can use Razor Pages, but you'll still need to write some Javascript to manipulate the HTML canvas.

Comment: Are you telling me your teacher wants you to create a diagram editor from scratch? If it's on the web you can do it with razor pages just fine. Can you use a third party library like https://www.syncfusion.com/aspnet-mvc-ui-controls/diagram?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you use on the front end, you can do it in HTML, css and Javascript.

Comment: Yes, i can use any libraries i want.But I'm jus a student, coding C++ and C#. I'm ready for new knowledges and languages, just hope that's not extreme hard task